# What is the meaning of "crank open" and "hung up" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is the context:

> **Tyson**: allow me to
>   announce that this day is the 25th anniversary of Kathy Sullivan deploying
>   the Hubble Space Telescope in space.
>
> **Kathryn Sullivan**: actually, I did not get to pull the trigger that released it. Steve Hawley did that. And Bruce McCandless and I were locked in
>   the airlock where we had almost had to race outside to
>   **crank open** the solar array that **hung up** for a while.
>
> source: 2015 Isaac Asimov Memorial Debate: Water, Water

What is the meaning of "crank open" in this context? and additionally, is "hung up" means "stop working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crank is a a device to increase torque to rotate something. An example is the crank between a bicycle pedal and the gear. From that comes the verb "to crank," i.e., to turn the handle of a crank.

[image: Crank]

The reason that Sullivan had to manually crank the array was, as you state, it had stopped working, or "hung up".

Comment: So, it means "fixing the solar array with turning the handle of a crank"?

Comment: Well, opening it with the crank.